# Question in the exactness of the induced sequence of an exact sequence of module homomorphisms using the representation functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I am referring to Theorem 6.3 p. 143 from Lang's Algebra (but the question description will be as self-contained as possible).

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$, $W$, $V$, $U$ be $A$-modules.
Let the sequence 
$$0 \longrightarrow W \stackrel{\lambda}{\longrightarrow} V 
\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} U \longrightarrow 0 $$
be exact.

By Proposition 2.1 p. 122, the induced sequence 
$$0\longrightarrow Hom_A(U,M) \stackrel{\phi'}\longrightarrow Hom_A(V,M) 
\stackrel{\lambda'}\longrightarrow Hom_A(W,M) $$ is exact.
If we let $M$ be $A$ as a module over itself, then we obtain
$$0 \longrightarrow Hom_A(U,A) \stackrel{\phi'}{\longrightarrow} Hom_A(V,A) 
\stackrel{\lambda'}{\longrightarrow} Hom_A(W,A)$$ exact or in
Lang's notation 
$$0 \longrightarrow U^{\vee} \stackrel{\phi'}{\longrightarrow} V^{\vee} 
\stackrel{\lambda'}{\longrightarrow} W^{\vee},$$ where $V^{\vee}$ is
the dual module of $V$.

Now, this is where i have a problem: it is mentioned in the proof of theorem 6.3 that
since $A$ is projective (because it is free), then we also have exactness from the right, i.e. 
$$0 \longrightarrow U^{\vee} \stackrel{\phi'}{\longrightarrow} V^{\vee} 
\stackrel{\lambda'}{\longrightarrow} W^{\vee} \longrightarrow 0$$ is exact. I don't see where this exactness from the right comes from since $A$ being projective means that the functor $Hom_A(A,\cdot)$ is exact, while to obtain dual spaces we use the functor
$Hom_A(\cdot,A)$.

Any insights?
Thank you:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that Lang assumes that the $A$-modules $W,V,U$ are finite free. The exactness of the dual sequence is then immediate.

Comment: I am studying the same problem after several months, i got stuck exactly at the same point and now i can not see why the exactness is immediate. Could you please give me a hint? Thanks.